# C++ SFML Static Links using Windows, Font.cpp error

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw, sfml

I'm using MinGW g++, added SFML lib to my project, builded with Cmake. Everything was fine, but then I was trying to display text using SFML Font/Text, and now I have got such errors, and cant find the issue on the Internet

thank you in advance!

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilNmb.png)

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q94Pq.png)

Comment: Those look like freetype functions. Add `-lfreetype` at the end.

Comment: Also please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: oh. thanks! ill try

Comment: actually now here's new error

Comment: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfreetype
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Then you need to download and compile freetype, or find a precompiled one somewhere. I recommend installing MSYS2: it comes with lots of prebuilt libraries (including freetype), and also with an up-to-date compiler (GCC 6.3 is old, we have 9.2 now).

Comment: thanks for the help a lot! i'll try